# Why FindBugs reports a possible NPE on an object annotated with @NotNull?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, annotations, findbugs

In the following code snipet

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class Foo {
    public static class Bar {
        private int number;
        public int getNumber() { 
            return number; 
        }
    }

    public int getNumberFromBar(@NotNull Bar bar) { 
        return bar.getNumber(); 
    }
}
```

I use the @NotNull annotation from org.jetbrains to tell the IntelliJ's static analyzer that the function parameter must not be null. When I however run FinBugs 3 on this code, it reports a possible Null Pointer exception on

```
return bar.getNumber();
```

Why is that? Am I missing here something?

This seems to me an incorrect behavior of FindBugs, especially in combination with the fact that when I remove the @NotNull annotation, FindBugs reports nothing. The internal IntelliJ's analyzer works with this annotation correctly.

Comment: Well, FindBugs probably doesn't know and care about IntelliJ annotations. Just like Amazon doesn't care about your Walmart coupons.

Comment: It seems to care about them incorrectly. If FindBugs would not have cared about them, nothing would be reported -- just like in the case with no annotation at all. Anyways, seems like some incompatibility issue here.

Comment: @random4212, I agree with your analysis.  You should [report a bug to FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/reportingBugs.html).  Before `@Nullable` confuses you too, note that [FindBugs's handling of `@Nullable` is non-standard](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#findbugs-nullable).